# How to pass the ids in model class in view to the controller along with some form data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: view page is Like this] Here am pressing the pay button i have to pass ids and the form data
in my view am displaying some data using **for each** loop,and when i click a button i have to pass the number of ids which returns in model class and some form data(which is outside the model class) to the controller,i have tried my maximum,But i failed,please help me to make this?

> view.cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <input type="hidden" value="@item.vid" name="abc" />//i need these ids in my controller
    <tr>

        <td>

        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.vid)</td>
       .........
         ...........//some more displaying
}
@Html.BeginForm("makepayment","home",FormMethod.Post)
{
<h3>Card Holder Name</h3>
        <input type="text" name="cname" />

       <h3>Account Name</h3>
  <input type="text" name="number" />
       <h3>CVC</h3>
     <input type="text" name="securitycode" />

       <h3>Expiery Date</h3>
     <input type="text" name="expdate" />



           <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="pay" />                    
  }
```

> controller

```
public ActionResult makepayment(FormCollection values,????)
         {
......
.......//codes
}
```

i know i may have to use array or something,but i dont know how,somebody please help

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is a ViewModel? Please a bit more context so we can try and recreate this.

Comment: @codeseeker Did you figure this out? You would need to place your `Form` in the entire page since you want to send data to the controller. You can access your  hidden `abc` by the `FormCollection` in your controller.

Comment: @Rahul Sharma, wat i have tried is.for(i=0;i<Model.count;i++){ int[] =new int[]{q[i]}<input type =hidden;value="q[0]">

Comment: @Rahul Sharma i tried my maximum, but i failed to find another solution than ths stupid idea.

Comment: @codeseeker That is fine. You are looping over your Model but you have to understand that you would have to place the `Form` tag on top of the `foreach` loop. When you hit the submit, your form values would be posted like this: `public ActionResult makepayment(FormCollection values,List<Model> yourmodel)`.

Answer (score -1):

Now, following semantics, you should create a separate viewmodel class that can hold such information, but that is not always the case.
So here is my understanding. You have a model class which you are what your form consists of, but you also want to send the ids that are just related to something else. In you post action, you get an instance of your model class with model binding.

```
//Please ignore the [] chars
public ActionResult makepayment([Name of you model class] modelInstance)
{
    //modelInstance will contain the fields of the model.
    //The remaining field, you can access using.
    //Request.Form["{name of the input field}"]
    var id = Request.Form["abc"]
}
```

Hope this helps you out. Otherwise, hit me with up and we can easily go through it in more detail.

```
P.S :- I am not a sir.
```

Comment: Thnq for ur response,the form doesn't contain my model class,only the id is consist inside model,form data dont have any relation with model class

Comment: that's okay, you can still use the Request.Form[] or go for List<int> {name of every id input field} .